# Spring Cache Abstraction with Hazelcast Doesn't Evict Key From Cache

Tags: spring-boot, caching, hazelcast, spring-cache

With the following configuration, my return object is cached but when I try to evict a key manually it doesnt't work.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class HazelCastConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public HazelcastCacheManager hazelcastCacheManager() {
        return new HazelcastCacheManager(Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelcastConfig()));
    }

    @Bean
    public Config hazelcastConfig() {
        return new Config()
                .setInstanceName("hazelcast-instance")
                .addMapConfig(new MapConfig()
                        .setName("myCache")
                        .setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig())
                        .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)
                        .setStatisticsEnabled(true)
                        .setTimeToLiveSeconds(-1));
    }
}
```

Cached method:

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value = "myCache", unless = "#result == null", key = "{#someString, #someLong, #someInteger}")
public List<MyReturnObject> methodWithCachedResults (String someString, Long someLong, Integer someInteger) { 
    //my logic 
}
```

A sample helper method:

```
public void evictKey(String aString, Long aLong, Integer anInteger) {
         IMap<Object, Object> hazelcastCache = Hazelcast.getHazelcastInstanceByName("hazelcast-instance").getMap("myCache");
         hazelcastCache.evict(Arrays.asList(aString, aLong, anInteger));
         logger.info("{}", hazelcastCache.keySet());
    }
```

When I trigger the method above, it logs the key even though I force the key to be evicted.

The result is the same when I try with the CacheManager :

```
@Autowired
private HazelcastCacheManager cacheManager;

public void evictKey(String aString, Long aLong, Integer anInteger) {

    cacheManager.getCache("myCache").evict(Arrays.asList(aString, aLong, anInteger));

}
```

However if I try this, it clears the whole cache which it obviously states:

```
public void evictKey(String aString, Long aLong, Integer anInteger) {
      IMap<Object, Object> hazelcastCache = Hazelcast.getHazelcastInstanceByName("hazelcast-instance").getMap("myCache");
      hazelcastCache.clear();
}
```

By the way, checking keySet().contains(Arrays.asList...) returns true.

Comment: And what makes you think storing all your elements in the list is the proper key? Because it isn't and becuase it isn't, the keys don't match and nothing will be evicted. What you should be using is a method annotated with `@CacheEvict` to remove elements from the cache, as that will recreate the proper key.

Comment: Actually, I have used EhCache implementation before and using that list as a key worked like a charm. I achieved to store elements in the cache and evict the cache in the same way I am trying now. I tried to use @CacheEvict and not using a list, and it still says that keySet() contains SimpleKey objects and not evicts keys.

Comment: In `logger.info("{}", hazelcastCache.keySet());` what is the type of the returned keys ? You're evicting a list key, but if the actual key isn't a list it won't find it.

Comment: As I said before, keySet().contains(Arrays.asList(aString, aLong, anInteger)) returns true. I mean, is there any possibilty that those lists are equal but not evictable ?

Comment: Looking at the actual hazelcast integration part they do a `delete` instead of an `evict`. However as mentioned I would strongly suggest to use the annotation or Spring cache abstraction to do the eviction instead of directly trying to access the cache.

Comment: As you suggested, I tried @CacheEvict annotation and the SimpleKey to Spring do the job and I had no luck. The results are the same and keys are not evicted from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

It's far from obvious, but there's two implementations of List here.

`@Cacheable` will create an instance of `java.util.ArrayList`.

`Arrays.asList` will create an instance of `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`.

This should make it clearer:

```
    public void evictKey(String aString, Long aLong, Integer anInteger) {
        IMap<Object, Object> hazelcastCache = Hazelcast.getHazelcastInstanceByName("hazelcast-instance").getMap("myCache");
        java.util.List<Object> keyToEvict = Arrays.asList(aString, aLong, anInteger);
        boolean success = hazelcastCache.evict(Arrays.asList(aString, aLong, anInteger));
        logger.info("Evicted {}, {} ==  {}", keyToEvict, keyToEvict.getClass(), success);
        for (Object key : hazelcastCache.keySet()) {
            logger.info("Remaining key {}, {}", key, key.getClass());
        }
   }
```